# Understanding proof for $e \leq 3v - 6$ in planar graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation, planar-graphs

I have a  proof for a property of a planar graph:

> **Lemma 5.8.4.** In a planar embedding of a connected graph, each edge is traversed once by each of two different faces, or is traversed exactly twice by one face.
>
> **Lemma 5.8.5**. In a planar embedding of a connected graph with at least three vertices, each face is of length at least three.
>
> Suppose a connected planar graph has $v \geq 3$ vertices and $e$ edges. Then
>
> $e \leq 3v - 6$
>
> **Proof.** By definition, a connected graph is planar iff it has a planar embedding. So suppose a connected graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges has a planar embedding with $f$ faces. By Lemma 5.8.4, every edge is traversed exactly twice by the face boundaries. So the sum of the lengths of the face boundaries is exactly 2e. Also by Lemma 5.8.5, when $v\geq 3$, each face boundary is of length at least three, so this sum is at least $3f$ . This implies that
>
> $3f\leq 2e$
>
> But $f = e - v + 2$ by Euler’s formula, and substituting into the above gives
>
> $3(e - v + 2) \leq 2e$
>
> $= e - 3v + 6 \leq 2e$
>
> $= e \leq 3v - 6$

*([Source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_chap05.pdf))*

I have been trying to wrap my head around this, but I don't really get it fully. My main issues are:

- Why do we start with $v\geq 3$? Because 3 is the minimum number of vertices needed to forma planar embedding with more than 1 face, or what's the reason?
- I'm also stuck on this:

> By Lemma 5.8.4, every edge is traversed exactly twice by the face boundaries. So the sum of the lengths of the face boundaries is exactly 2e. Also by Lemma 5.8.5, when $v\geq 3$, each face boundary is of length at least three, so this sum is at least $3f$ . This implies that
>
> $3f\leq 2e$

Why do the two lemmas imply that $3f$ is lower or equal to $2e$? I understand each lemma on it's own, but I dont follow that conclusion, to be honest.

What is also the significance of this? From what I get, this formula gives an upper-bound on the number of edges in a planar graph, it's then used to proof that a graph is planar nor not, depending on the number of edges, is that right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, the reason for $v\geq3$ is that the result would be messier and there are no interesting graphs with 2 or fewer vertices. I think you are missing the significance of the fact that the side length of a face is greater than or equal to $3$. This is because side length counts edges twice if they are traversed twice when moving around the perimeter of the face. For example, the face $F_1$ has a side length of $7$.
[image: The face $F_1$ has side length $7$]
Similarly, the following graph has a side length of $4$, even though there are only two edges:[image]
 Combining this with the fact that each edge is traversed twice by faces (either two different faces, or the same face twice), we have a relation between faces and edges in a planar graph. Namely, if we sum the lengths of each face, we know we count each edge twice, thus this sum is precisely $2e$. The least number of edges a face can have is three, so the smallest the sum of the length of each face can be is $3f$. So, $3f$ is also the smallest the value $2e$ can be, since this is the same as the sum of the side lengths of the faces. Thus
$$3f\leq 2e$$.

The significance of all this is that we now have a way to show that a given graph is not planar. For example the complete graph on $5$ vertices is not planar since we have $4+3+2+1=10$ edges and $5$ vertices so that we have $3v-6=15-6=9$ which is less than $10$, the number of edges. Also this captures something intuitive about planar graphs, things go wrong when one has too many edges for the number of vertices,

Comment: "The least number of edges a face can have is three" - I'm a bit confused about this statement. If I just have a line graph, connecting A-B-C (no connection from A to C, then I have 2 edges, no?

Comment: I think you mean maybe "the least number of vertices in a face is three".

Comment: Ah, no. This is a subtle point, but when an edge is bounded by the same face on both sides, then that face counts that edge twice when computing edge length. So, your three vertices and two edges gives rise to a single face with side length equal to 4

Comment: Ah, yeah, ok, that makes sense then that the same edge is counted twice. Thanks for clarification with the images!

Answer (score 5):

A [maximal planar (or triangulated) graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangulatedGraph.html) is a [simple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) planar graph that can have no more edges added to it without making it non-planar. All the faces of a maximal planar graph will be triangular (bounded by exactly three edges).

*(Note: Any non-maximal planar graph can be made into a maximal planar graph by adding edges between two non-adjacent vertices bounding the same face to bisect that face until all the faces are triangular and no further bisections are possible.)*

Since each face of a maximal-planar graph is bounded by exactly 3 edges and each edge will be on the boundary of exactly two faces then:

\begin{align}
3F = 2E
\end{align}

Substituting this into the [Euler Characteristic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerCharacteristic.html) (where, for an 2D plane, $\chi\left(g\right)=2$) then the number of edges in a maximal-planar graph is given by:

\begin{align}
 V &= 2 + E - F \\
 V &= 2 + E - \frac{2E}{3} \\
 3V &= 6 + E \\
 3V - 6 &= E \\
\end{align}

Since any planar graph must have equal to or fewer edges than a maximal planar graph with the same number of vertices then all planar graphs must have:

\begin{align}
E \le 3V - 6 
\end{align}

However, you can also get the the same solution noting that if the graph is not maximal planar then the average number of edges per face will be greater than 3 so:

\begin{align}
3F \le 2E
\end{align}

Then substituting this gives:

\begin{align}
 V & = 2 + E - F \\
 V & \ge 2 + E - \frac{2E}{3} \\
 3V &\ge 6 + E \\
 3V - 6 &\ge E \\
\end{align}

> What is also the significance of this? From what I get, this formula gives an upper-bound on the number of edges in a planar graph, it's then used to proof that a graph is planar nor not, depending on the number of edges, is that right?

This cannot prove that a simple graph is planar (for example: [$K_{(3,3)}$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteBipartiteGraph.html) has 6 vertices and 9 edges, so $E \le 3V - 6$ is true but the graph is actually non-planar) but it can give an easy calculation to demonstrate that a simple graph is non-planar (for example: [$K_5$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteGraph.html) has 5 vertices and 10 edges so $E \le 3V - 6$ is false and cannot be planar).

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I found the examples quite helpfull to understand that we can say if  a simple graph is non-planar.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is rather straightforward once you have discovered another property, which is that, for a planar graph $G = (V, E)$, $3f \leq 2|E|$ where $f$ is the number of faces in the planar drawing of $G$. A proof of this inequality can be found here:

[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897815/what-is-the-definition-of-faces-in-graph-theory-why-does-3f≤2e-hold-for-any-c/4517140#4517140](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897815/what-is-the-definition-of-faces-in-graph-theory-why-does-3f%E2%89%A42e-hold-for-any-c/4517140#4517140)

The rest of this proof can be accomplished algebraically as follows:

By Euler's formula, $f = 2 - |V| + |E|$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
             3f = 6 - 3|V| + 3|E| &\leq 2|E| \\
             3|E| - 2|E| &\leq 3|V| - 6 \\
             |E| &\leq 3|V| - 6 \: 
     \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Others gave reasons why $v\geq 3$ is considered. I'll give a proof built on a nice "explainer" combinatorics trick I found while reading KöMaLs in high school:

Take the set of face-edge pairs, where the face includes the edge among its edges. Say, the number of such pairs (cardinality of the set) is $M$. For example, in a tetrahedron, there are 12 such pairs, because each face has 3 edges.

What do we know about $M$?
Because every edge "divides" two faces, every edge appears in exactly two pairs, thus we know that the number of pairs is double the number of edges: $M=2e$.
On the other hand, every face is a polygon, each face has at least 3 edges. Therefore, every face appears in at least 3 pairs. This means that $M\geq 3f$. If all faces are triangles, then the two are equal, but if any face has more than 3 edges, it appears in more than 3 pairs in the set, and therefore we cannot have equality in that case.

From the two you can deduct that $2e\geq 3f$.