# Can someone explain to me the significance of $e \leq 3v-6$ in graph theory?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm studying for a final and my textbook often uses the equation
$$
e \le 3v-6
$$ 
(seems to be a theory or corollary) for some of the graph theory proofs, but I can't find anywhere as to where this equation is derived from therefore making it hard for me to attempt to use it as part of a solution.

> Could someone please tell me how it's derived and why it's significant?

Much Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For a  simple, connected, planar graph with $v \ge 3$ vertices and $e$ edges,
$e \le 3 v - 6$.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Other_planarity_criteria).

Comment: does this change at all if the faces were per se, a pentagon?

Answer (score 2):

This is only applicable to planar graphs, for instance $K_5$ has $5$ vertices but $10 > 15 - 6$ edges. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414843/understanding-proof-for-e-leq-3v-6-in-planar-graphs) will give you a proof to this common theorem.

Comment: does this change at all if the faces were per se, a pentagon?

Comment: You can shape the faces however you want, but $K_5$ will be non-planar no matter how you draw it.

Answer (score 1):

This formula is valid specifically for *planar graphs*. If a graph with $3$ or more vertices is planar, and $e$ is the number of edges and $v$ the number of vertices of that graph, then it is true that
$$
e \leq 3v-6
$$

Comment: does this change at all if the faces were per se, a pentagon?

Comment: @DevAllanPer You won't get equality if there are pentagonal faces (note that each pentagonal face can be made into three triangular faces by adding two edges between the vertices). So it could be strengthened. To what? I don't know. Something like (I'm just guessing wildly here) $e\leq v + 3$, perhaps? A closer look with Euler's formula will probably reveal an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a planar graph and let $F$ denote the number of faces and $E$ denote the number of edges, and $V$ denote the number of vertices. Euler's formula says that $V-E+F=2$ which means $F=2+E-V$.
On the other hand, the length of perimeter surrounding a face is at least $3$. So then if we sum up the length of each face, which is twice number of edges, we get:
$6+3E-3V=3(2+E-V)=F*3 \leq \sum_{f \in face(G)}{len(f)}=2*E$. which means $E \leq 3V-6$.

Answer (score 0):

That's the number of edges in a planar graph with all faces triangles, and thus the highest possible number of edges in a planar graph.
\begin{align*}V+F &= E+2\\
V+\frac23 E &= E+2\\
V-2 &= \frac13E\\
3V-6 &= E\end{align*}

Comment: So does it change if the faces were per se, a pentagon?

Comment: Faces with more edges lead to fewer total edges. Of course, we could always draw in new edges in each face, cutting them up until only triangles remain.