# What is the source of the property: $e=3v-6$ for planar graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Where does the result
$$
e=3v-6
$$

For planar graphs come from?

I can't find an original source for this property

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414843/understanding-proof-for-e-leq-3v-6-in-planar-graphs

Comment: Thank you @higgs but I'm looking for the original source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding proof for $e \leq 3v - 6$ in planar graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414843/understanding-proof-for-e-leq-3v-6-in-planar-graphs)

Comment: Thanks! this is the same link as @higgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of this relation really is Euler, if one sets up a simple planar graph, $\Gamma$ with at least three vertices and two edges, it can be shown that

$$\frac{2}{3}f \leq e \leq 3v-6$$

for faces, $f$, edges $e$ and vertices $v$.

For a further consideration see [Planar Graph theory, here](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/sec_planar.html)

Comment: Hi, would it be possible if you can help with some graph theory problems? Like in a room chat or something? I just have many problems, and instead of posting for each on stackoverflow, and you answer regardless here, I thought you may help this way, as I checked the users and found you good at discrete mathematics,