# What is the definition of faces in Graph Theory? Why does 3f≤2|E| hold for any connected planar graph?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

From Euler's characteristic, we know any connected planar graph $G = (V, E)$ satisfies $|V|-|E|+f=2$ where $f$ is the numbers of faces in the drawing of $G$. Why do trees have 1 face? Because you can't form more than 1 face without a Jordan Curve and trees do not contain cycles. So I want know the strict definition of faces mathematically, and why $3f≤2|E|$ holds for any connected planar graph?

Comment: A facet is not a feature inherent to a graph, unlike edges and vertices, but rather, of an embedding of a (geometric realization of a) graph on a surface. A facet is a connected component of the complement of the embedding.

Comment: Why does tree have 1 facet? @tomasz

Comment: A tree will always have 1 facet (when embedded on a connected surface), basically because it is contractible.

Comment: What is a connected surface? @tomasz

Comment: It's a surface that is connected. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space

Comment: When a graph is embedded on a surface, this surface will be counted to be a facet? @tomasz

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a formal definition of faces, but if you consider the set of all points in the plane that do not lie on any arcs of a given drawing, there are finitely many connected regions (a region is connected if for any two arbitrary points in the region, there exists an arc whose endpoints are those two endpoints (note that arcs cannot intersect by the definition of a drawing)). These regions are referred to as faces. Also note that the existence of at least 2 faces requires the existence of a Jordan Curve. While there is a Jordan Curve Theorem that makes this assertion, this should also be clear intuitively since a single Jordan Curve "implies" 2 regions (the interior and exterior of the Jordan Curve).

Now to prove your proposed inequality...

***Proof:***
Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected, planar graph with $|V| \geq 3$, and let $f$ be the number of faces in a planar drawing of $G$.

Suppose $G$ has $f$ faces and let $\beta$ : $F_i \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a function that counts the number of edges along the boundary of a given face, $F_i$ $(i \in \{ 1,$..., $f \})$, in a drawing of $G$.

Case 1: $G$ is not a tree.

Then, $f > 1$. Suppose all $e_{i} \in E(G)$ are in a Jordan curve. By the Jordan Curve Theorem, $e_{i}$ bounds $2$ faces in $G$. More concretely, if we let $F_i$ and $F_j$ ($i, j \in \{ 1,$..., $f \}, i \neq j$) be the two faces bounded by some edge $e_i$, $\beta(F_i)$ and $\beta(F_j)$ will both count the edge $e_i$. Thus, $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{f} \beta(F_i) = 2|E|$ because each edge is counted twice. Now consider that there exists an edge $e_t$ such that $e_t$ bounds only one face (i.e. $e_t$ is not part of a Jordan curve). Then, $e_t$ is counted only once because $e_t$ is not counted as a bounding edge for a second face. Thus, $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{f} \beta(F_i) \leq 2|E|$.
Now consider the minimum number of edges bounding a given face $F_i$. Every face is bounded by a Jordan curve and thus, every face is bounded by a minimum of three edges (a Jordan curve must have at least 3 edges since any 2 vertices cannot share more than one edge). However, there can, of course, be more than three edges in a Jordan curve, thus, $3 \leq \beta(F_i)$. Thus, $3f \leq \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{f} \beta (F_i)$.

Combining these two inequalities, we get $3f \leq \displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{f} \beta(F_i) \leq 2|E|$.

Case 2: $G$ is a tree.

Then, $f = 1$ and $3f = 3$. Since $|V| \geq 3$ and $G$ is connected, it must be true that $|E| \geq 2$ and $2|E| \geq 4$. Clearly $3f = 3 < 4 \leq 2|E|$, which satisfies the proposed inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It's a double counting argument.

Each face has at least 3 edges, and each edges is in (at most) 2 faces.

Do you see how to set it up?

Comment: Why $f=1$ in tree graph?