# If $G$ is a connected planar graph then with at least three vertices, $e$ edges and $r$ regions, prove that $e \leq 3n - 6$.

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[(source)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414843/understanding-proof-for-e-leq-3v-6-in-planar-graphs)

Lemma 5.8.4. In a planar embedding of a connected graph, each edge is traversed once by each of two different regions, or is traversed exactly twice by one region.

Lemma 5.8.5. In a planar embedding of a connected graph with at least three vertices, each region is of length at least three.

Suppose a connected planar graph has $v\geq 3$ vertices and $e$ edges. Then

$$e\leq 3v−6.$$

Proof. By definition, a connected graph is planar iff it has a planar embedding. So suppose a connected graph with v vertices and e edges has a planar embedding with r region. By Lemma 5.8.4, every edge is traversed exactly twice by the region boundaries. So the sum of the lengths of the region boundaries is exactly 2e. Also by Lemma 5.8.5, when v≥3, each region boundary is of length at least three, so this sum is at least 3r . This implies that

3r≤2e

But r=e−v+2 by Euler’s formula, and substituting into the above gives

3(e−v+2)≤2e

=e−3v+6≤2e

=e≤3v−6

My question is that "sum of the lengths of the region boundaries is exactly 2e" doesn't quite makes sense. How can I understand the "2e" part according to number of edges, cause it looks like 2e should be total/maximum number of regions if we have e edges in a graph and each edge contributes to 2 regions.

Comment: Do you imagine that we are aware of a certain proof using the fact that "the max edges is 2e" ? You have to give a reference ! Moreover, expression "the max edges is 2e" is far from clear... Transform your unique non-understandable sentence into 4 or 5 clear sentences.

Comment: There's so much context missing from your post that I cannot guess what you might be asking. Take a look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and in particular look at how to [provide missing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding proof for $e \leq 3v - 6$ in planar graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2414843/understanding-proof-for-e-leq-3v-6-in-planar-graphs)

Comment: @JeanMarie please see now. I already checked the other link, but that still didn't clear my confusion.

Comment: One more clarifying question: I cannot see where it says "max. edges is $2e$", so can you explain exactly where in this proof you are referring to? What I see instead is "the sum of the lengths of the face boundaries is exactly $2e$".

Comment: @LeeMosher, please check now.

Comment: The phrase "sum of the lengths of the region boundaries is exactly 2e" is not good notation at all. I'd formalise it for you. Given a region (or face) $R$ of the graph, let $e_R$ be the subset of edges that "surround" $R$. What Lemma 5.8.4 says is that:
$$\sum_{\text{all regions } R \text{ in } G} |e_R| = 2e.$$ I assume this is what is meant by ""sum of the lengths of the region boundaries is exactly 2e" as well. Does this clarify?